# Twitter oauth_signature process

Tags: twitter, oauth, sha1

I am hoping to get a little bit of help.

I am going through the oauth_signature process and I am working with the default data that they have on there -  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

My question is that no matter what I do, I can't get the SHA1 hash to produce the same result that they are showing I should be coming up with.

I even go to an only SHA1 converter tool online and it produces a completely separate result.

[image]

Again, this is using the signature base string and the signature key that they are supplying, but the result does not match and it should.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

I have tried multiple has methods to try to get the same result.